# Multiple belongs_to to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have two tables:

currencies and rates

```
currencies: id:int, code:string, name: string

rates: id:int, top_currency_id:int, bottom_currency_id:int, rate:float
```

And I have two active records for them:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bottom_currency, :rate, :top_currency, :top_currency_id

  belongs_to :top_currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'top_currency_id'
  belongs_to :bottom_currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'bottom_currency_id'
end


class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :name

  has_many :rates
end
```

So the problem is:
When I'm tring to execute following code:
    top_currency        = Currency.find_by_id(1)
    @test = Rate.where(:top_currency=>top_currency)

I getting following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'rates.top_currency' in 
'where clause': SELECT `rates`.* FROM `rates`  WHERE `rates`.`top_currency` = 1
```

Why Rails's magic doesn't work?

Many thanks.

Comment: The error states that `top_currency` isn't a column in the `rates` table, are you sure you migrated your changes to the environment you're using?

Comment: @JaredMcAteer I have top_currency_id column, and I supposed that Rails should look for top_currency_id column insted of top_currency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your two `belongs_to` methods, change the `foreign_key` option to `primary_key`, leaving everything else as is.

```
belongs_to :top_currency, :class_name => 'Currency', :primary_key => 'top_currency_id'
# ...
```

By default, an associated object's primary key is `id`. However, your currency model has three  primary keys, the expected `id` plus two extra keys: `top_currency_id` and `bottom_currency_id`. Active Record needs to know which key to look for. Tell it with the `primary_key` option.

The `foreign_key` option is needed when a foreign key is different than the association's name (`belongs_to :name`) plus "`_id`". Since your foreign key matches the association name plus "`_id`," you do not need to use the `foreign_key` option.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have only one primary key.

Answer (score 5):

From what I see, your code should work in theory. But I do think you are being a bit redundant.

It should be enough to just do this:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :top_currency, class_name: 'Currency'
  belongs_to :bottom_currency, class_name: 'Currency'
end
```

Rails will infer that the foreign key for `top_currency` is `top_currency_id`, and `bottom_currency_id` for `bottom_currency`.

Comment: Are you sure that the class name shouldn't be a symbol or string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can query on the relationship like that.  To use your example:

```
top_currency = Currency.find_by_id(1)
@test = Rate.where(:top_currency=>top_currency)
```

You'd have to change it to this:

```
top_currency = Currency.find_by_id(1)
@test = Rate.where(:top_currency_id => top_currency.id)
```

But it might just be easier to do this:

```
top_currency = Currency.find_by_id(1)
@test = top_currency.rates
```

Comment: Yes, `@test = Rate.where(:top_currency_id => top_currency.id)` even `@test = Rate.where(:top_currency_id => top_currency)` works well. But I want to make `Rate.where(:top_currency=>top_currency)` works

Comment: Just curious as to why are you so committed on having `Rate.where(:top_currency=>top_currency)` when the association you set up gives you the method `top_currency.rates`to do the same thing?

Comment: @MollyStruve in fact I need to execute following request: `Rate.where(:top_currency=>top_currency, :bottom_currency=>bottom_curency)`

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't do that.  Add _id to each of the symbols and it'll work. I see what you're going for, but it's not possible in a simple query. You're looking to do a join, which is much more expensive than simply checking for the id of the related records.